# encodeURIComponent not working with array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to pass data between pages using Javascript, and I need to decode a pair of number that will be passed from Page1 to Page2.
The array containing the number is a `JSON.parse` result from an `AJAX` request to `PHP` file, that queries a `SQL DB` (you can now release your breath).

```js
response = '[{"id":"3","course_category":"Dancing & Fitness"}, {"id":"2","course_category":"Fighting"}]';
var myArray = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(myArray[1]['id']);
var foo = encodeURIComponent(myArray[1]['id']);
console.log(foo);
```

the encode always shows

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

which is funny, because the first `console.log` always returns **a correct number**. I've also tried to do this

```
var foo=encodeURIComponent(myArray[1]['id']).toString();
```

but no luck.
What am I doing wrong?

Example JSON parsed data

```
console.log(myArray[0]['id']) //-->shows 3
```

The function handling the ChangePageEvent

```
$("#el" + (myArray[i].id).on("click", function () {
    var url = "single_course_page.html?idcat=" + encodeURIComponent(myArray[i].id);
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

Comment: Can you show us an example response?

Comment: It's in JSON data format, like this
`[{"id":"3","course":"Dancing & Fitness"}]`

Comment: We don't know what your `response` is or `$myArray`. Could you paste the value of it so we can see the variable's value?

Comment: Unlikely that the number in your console comes from that `console.log` if accessing `.id` throws an error. Also try logging `$myArray[1]` on itself.

Comment: Remember that arrays are 0-based. Are you sure you have more than one element in `$myArray`

Comment: I've edited the first post, I mistakenly added the $, but not in my actual code

Comment: please use https://jsfiddle.net/ to add an example

Comment: Your post still contains discrepancies- sometimes it's $myarray and sometimes myarray (no $).

Comment: I've added the function calling the `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: Looks like a closure issue with i inside click handler. Still missing some relevant context in question. Just check i in handler. And im not sure how this is related to your previous posted snippet

Comment: `$("#el" + myArray[i].id)` remove the extra  `(`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it. It was a callback funcion problem. I modified the click handler like this.

```
$("#el"+myArray[1].id).on("click", changePagePassingData(id));


function changePagePassingData(id){
return function(){
    var url = "single_course_page.html?idcat=" + encodeURIComponent(id);

        window.location.href = url;
       }
}
```

Comment: Suppose Page1 as a list of Books, and when I click on a Book it redirects to Page 2, which contains all the data of the single book. I want this for every book, so I keep only two pages and pass the identifier of the book from Page1 to Page2. I have to this without using PHP for a project assignment.

Comment: But i meant `encodeURIComponent(id)` if `id` is always a string number, you don't need to use `encodeURIComponent()` method: `encodeURIComponent escapes all characters except the following: alphabetic, decimal digits, - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )`  So `encodeURIComponent(id) === id`. It would be useful if you pass more complex string as ones containing spaces e.g in your case passing `response.course_category` in URL

Comment: Ah good, didn't think about that. I thought it was a standard thing to do when copying values into an url (like data formatting for URI, or something). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is simply the best in my opinion.

```js
var obj={"test":"teser", confs:["fdf","dfg"]};

var url=encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Now,

```
url="%7B%22test%22%3A%22teser%22%2C%22confs%22%3A%5B%22fdf%22%2C%22dfg%22%5D%7D"
```

If you do `JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(url))` you'll get original object. Similarly for arrays..

Answer (score 0):

For generating query parameters i'm using the following:

```
export const objectToQuerystring = (obj: Dictionary<any>, encode = true): string => {
const doEncode = (val: any) : any => {
    if(encode) return encodeURIComponent(val);
    return val;
}
return Object.keys(obj).reduce((str, key, i) => {
    key = doEncode(key);
    const delimiter = i === 0 ? '?' : '&';
    if(Array.isArray(obj[key])){
        const keyAndVal = obj[key].map((v, i )=> `${i === 0 ? delimiter : '&'}${key}=${doEncode(v)}`).join('')
        return [str, keyAndVal].join('');
    }
    const val = doEncode(obj[key]);
    return [str, delimiter, key, '=', val].join('');
}, '');
```

};

Answer (score -2):

Be sure that what your passing to the parse method is a string:

```
JSON.parse('STRINGIFIED OBJECT') //Takes a string
```

You cannot JSON.parse([anArray]);

At that point you can access your first index of the array with dot notation:

```
var myarray = JSON.parse('[{"id":"3","course_category":"Dancing & Fitness"},{"id":"2","course_category":"Fighting"}]');

myarray[0].id //Outputs 3
myarray[1].id //Outputs 2
```

Comment: A PHP result is a string. Always.

Comment: Still not working. I'll post the function that handles the change page event

Comment: Updated to hold your dataset